# Getting Syntax error in Jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

```
String name = request.getParameter("uname");
${param.uname};
```

I am getting below error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete
```

Please any one can solve this problem?

Comment: Please post the whole code of jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = request.getParameter("uname");
```

The line above is Java code, can be included in a [scriptlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages).

```
${param.uname}
```

The line above is [Unified Expression Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language)

Both lines can't be included in the same block without separators.